# What does $f([n]) = h([n]) = X$ mean in functions, if $h$ is bijective and $X$ is a countable set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

What is the meaning of the [] brackets?
It was given that bijection h : [n] → X

Comment: You're asking what the notation refers to, correct? This needs some clarification. It might refer to the greatest integer function, or it might refer to some equivalence class. Where did you encounter this notation?

Comment: It depends on the situation. $[x]$ is a common notation for the equivalence class of $x$ with respect to some equivalence relation. But for $n\in\Bbb N$ some use $[n]$ to indicate $\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, 0\le x<n\}$, or even $\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, 0\le x\le n\}$. It might be something else entirely.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking what the notation means. It was used in proving that f is a surjective function. It's not equivalence class.

Comment: So [n] is basically the number of elements?

Comment: In this case, it probably refers to the [floor/greatest integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably from the definition of 'finiteness' of the set $X$, whence $[n]$ denotes the $n$ element set $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.